# Replace single slash with double slash in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file, operating-system

Want to convert below path from single slash to double slash but when i print file its removing \b and \U as its special char in python. And for \U its gives unicode error.

```
file = "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ProjectShadow\button\button.py"
```

Expected output :

```
file = "C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\ProjectShadow\\button\\button.py"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can use `file = r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ProjectShadow\button\button.py"`. As described in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html. As a result, in string literals, '\U' and '\u' escapes in raw strings are not treated specially. Given that Python 2.x’s raw unicode literals behave differently than Python 3.x’s the 'ur' syntax is not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `r` for raw string and replace all single slashes with double slashes using the `str.replace` method.

```
file = r"C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\ProjectShadow\button\button.py"
file = file.replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

```
C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\ProjectShadow\\button\\button.py
```

Answer (score -1):

```
path = "C:\U0005\b000"

# replace single slash with double slash
double_slash_path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\")

# escape special characters
double_slash_path = double_slash_path.replace("\b", "\\b")
double_slash_path = double_slash_path.replace("\U", "\\U")

print(double_slash_path)
```